# Trying to pickup user who owns a record from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Comments controller which is utilised in 2 other controllers (Task & Ticket).

I'm trying to have it email the owner of the Ticket once a comment has been created to notify them that the Ticket has been updated.

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:ticket_owner])

    if @comment.save
        TicketMailer.comment_update(@user).deliver
```

I have a hidden field in the comments on the ticket show page

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :record_id, :value => @ticket.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :ticket_owner, :value => @ticket.user_id %>
```

I've tried every possible combination to my noob rails knowledge and this is the closest I've got.

```
NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

I can have it email my own username if i pass @user = current_user, but that's not the aim.

Comment: Inspect the params in the controller. I don't think you are getting the id in ticket_owner

Comment: I can see that the ticket_owner data has been written to the DB fine for it. I'm not quite sure what you mean by inspect the params in the controller though as what I've pasted above is the controller

Comment: Could you post the server logs for create request?

Comment: Want me to post it with my original code or your version?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cyKpxP16 - with my original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a FormBuilder to generate a form for your model, it generates fields with names like "model_name[attribute_name]".  In your case, if you inspect the HTML generated by your form partial, you should see (approximately):

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment[record_id]" />
<input type="hidden" name="comment[ticket_owner]" />
```

In the controller, these inputs are automatically grouped in the hash `params[:comment]`.  The name of the attribute is a key on the `params[:comment]` hash, not the `params` hash.  Your controller is getting a `nil` value for `params[:ticket_owner]`.  Instead, you should be looking for `params[:comment][:ticket_owner]`.

Comment: How did I miss this! Excellent, updated it with params[:comment][:ticket_owner] and it worked perfectly. Is there anything bad about the code I've wrote? It feels a bit hacky.

Comment: I'd probably but the `TicketMailer#comment_update` call in the `Comment` class as an `after_save` callback.  You could also set up an `ActiveRecord::Observer` to send the email when a `Comment` is saved.  There are some good answers elsewhere on this site that compare those approaches & show how to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:ticket][:user_id])

    if @comment.save
        TicketMailer.comment_update(@user).deliver

<%= f.hidden_field :ticket, :id, :name => "ticket[id]", :value => @ticket.id%>
<%= f.hidden_field :ticket, :user_id, :name => "ticket[user_id], :value => @ticket.user_id"%>
```

Comment: NoMethodError in Tickets#show  Showing app/views/tickets/show.html.erb where line #70 raised:  
undefined method `merge' for :id:Symbol`  It doesn't appear to like the hidden_field changes